# models.py and views.py may be conflicting

Tags: python, django

Below are the output of the models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
#from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Registration(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Registration.objects.create(username=instance)
    instance.registration.save()
```

Below is the output of the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.views import generic

class IndexView(generic.View):
    templet_name = 'user_info/index.html'


def signupview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('registration_form.html')

    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request,'user_info/registration_form.html',  {'form': form})
```

I have two questions:

1) In my models.py I have 4 fields, 'user','username','password','email'. In my first field "user", I guess, I shouldn't be using "models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)", because, as per my understanding, it's used when we have a primary key and foreign key in working. Please correct me if I am wrong.

2) in my views.py, the function "signupview", I am saving the form in the database through form.save(), and then cleaned the data. have I done the right thing, as my models.py has 4 fields, but in view.py , I am giving only two fields

```
username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
```

I hope I am making sense here. I am getting an error while creating a superuser through

```
python manage.py createsupseruser
```

Below is the error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: user_info_registration.user_id
```

That is why I am asking these questions.

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
#from django.forms import ModelForm

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    #first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    #last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password1','email')
```

Latest look of models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Registration(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: No, you're not making sense. Why do you have that Registration model? All those fields are already on User. The only reason to have a separate model is if you want to store extra information not already in the User model. Apart from anything else, you must not store password in plain text; that's why the User model has methods to set the password. Just remove Registration completely.

Comment: when I remove the registration model and try to createsuperuser, I get "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username" error

Comment: Where is the definition of SignupForm?

Comment: added in my original query

Comment: Actually I just noticed that your question is about createsuperuser. So the forms and views don't have anything at all to do with it; I don't really understand why your title talks about views conflicting. In any case, please post the code you are now using and the full traceback.

Comment: I differ, because, as soon as I made the changes in models.py, and now I am trying to create superuser, I am getting error "TypeError: 'user' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Comment: in my new signal has "User.objects.create(user=instance)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158082/discussion-between-user3521180-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: Now that you've deleted the Registration model, what makes you think you need a signal at all? You don't. Delete that too. (And this still has nothing to do with forms or views.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is that the `User` post save signal tries to create a `Registration` instance, but you don't supply values for all the required fields.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Registration.objects.create(username=instance) 
    instance.registration.save()
```

You either have to remove this signal handler or you have to provide valid arguments to `Registration.objects.create()`.

Comment: PS: I assume this app is a learning exercise. You should read the django documentation carefully and understand it before you decide to write your own code to handle passwords and user details. The django user authentication system is written by experts. If you write your own code to handle passwords etc. there's a huge risk that your app will be _very insecure_. It's like buying a super expensive home security system, and then putting the key and alarm password under the doormat for anyone to find.

Comment: So, if I have understood correctly unless I wish to extend the user authentication, I shouldn't overwrite the default "User" model. And since I am not customizing anything, I don't need customized signal as well. the signal part is also taken care by "User" model if I am using the default settings, please correct me if I am wrong. Then, if I am right about my understanding, the models.py would be empty. I have added the snippet in my original query with my current look of models.py

Comment: last but not the least, I have gone through the django 1.11 docs for "User" model. All it has got is a bunch of function mentioned there. It is not explaining, how to use them and where to use them, If you can help me with that part, it would be great.

Comment: You can create a custom user model by subclassing AbstractBaseUser. That way you can use the existing password and authentication system, and just add extra fields that are not security critical to your custom user model. The relevant docs are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: well, I guess, that is what I wanted. Thank you. thread can be concluded